# How to render a view from the Service layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm including a feature in my web application that notifies a user via e-mail.

Now that I want to HTML format this e-mail, I'm wondering whether it is viable to re-use the core functionality of ASP.NET MVC and have a partial view rendered to a string, so that I can make a partial view with the content of the e-mail. The code in the Service layer would provide the model necessary for the view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These days, there's [Postal](https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal) for that.

Check out Postal on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/postal/).

Answer (score 1):

You can call the view's `RenderView` method.

Note that this methods takes a [`ViewContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext.aspx) object, which you'll need to create yourself from the view, the relevant data, and a [`ControllerContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.aspx).  I'm not sure which of the properties in `ControllerContext` are actually used by the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can render view or partial to string:
http://www.brightmix.com/blog/how-to-renderpartial-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc/

You do actually need partial, not view, since you probably don't need master page layout with menus and login buttons inside your email ;-)

Note that in the link above there's another link to a shorter method.

Comment: I would update the answer with this: http://www.brightmix.com/blog/renderpartial-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc/ It's a much cleaner version of the original.

Comment: I actually mentioned that there's a shorter method.